# Unable to Install Python Package

Tags: python, windows, pip, mingw, anaconda

In trying to install a python package via pip I get the error:

```
  Failed building wheel for atari-py
  Running setup.py clean for atari-py
Failed to build atari-py
Installing collected packages: atari-py, PyOpenGL
  Running setup.py install for atari-py ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\xxxxxx\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-qhuh1q\\atari-py\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\xxxxxx\appdata\local\temp\pip-z8wnzs-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    Unable to execute 'make build -C atari_py/ale_interface -j 3'. HINT: are you sure `make` is installed?
    error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

In my system when I type make:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx>make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So, clearly make is missing. But I installed make using conda:

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx>conda install mingw
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2:
#
mingw                     4.7
```

So I have mingw 4.7 already installed.

How could I remove the error and get the package?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` is not in your PATH.
Do `echo %PATH%` and check if the path to your msys utilities is in there. Otherwise you can edit this variable by following the instructions here: [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Comment: how to get the msys utilities path? msys is in which folder.. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: thanks, C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\MinGW is my MingW path, adding it to the path disn't help.

Comment: I guess that the appropriate path is C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\MinGW\bin , (additional \bin at the end)

Comment: Hi, in bin folder I do not see any make.exe